# Can I compute contour orientation without using polygon area sign?

Tags: geometry, area, orientation, winding-number

Most of the times, I determine contour orientation generating 2D points and computing the closed polygon area. Depending on the area value sign I can understand if the contour is oriented clockwise or not (see [How to determine if a list of polygon points are in clockwise order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165647/how-to-determine-if-a-list-of-polygon-points-are-in-clockwise-order)).

Would it be possible to do the same computations without generating 2D points? I mean, relying only on geometric curve properties?

We are interested in determining the orientation of contours like these ones without sampling them with 2D points.

[image]

Comment: How are defined your curves? You could use numerical integration to compute the area of the curve.

Comment: We have all the geometric data for lines and arcs, we also know if the arc plane has Z-axis toward +1 or -1 (CW/CCW). Can you make/point to an example? Thank you.